# Permission denied (publickey) after running Ansible role to disable password login

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that does the following:

1. I generate SSH keys for the remote server
2. Then I disable root login and password authentication in the role `ssh`
3. Finally, I set the password for the root account.

The 2) and 3) part of the playbook are shown below:

```
- hosts: new_servers
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - block:

      - name: Run ssh role to enable login using SSH keys and disable password login
        include_role:
          name: ssh

      - name: Set Password on root Account
        user:
          name: user
          password: "{{ user_password_hash }}"
          update_password: always
```

The `ssh` role has the following `tasks/main.yml`, taking inspiration from [this link](https://medium.com/@khandelwal12nidhi/setup-ssh-key-and-initial-user-using-ansible-playbook-61eabbb0dba4):

```
---

- name: Set SSH port
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: "^Port\\s"
    line: "Port {{ ssh_port }}"
    state: present
  notify: Restart SSH

- name: Disable root SSH login
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: "^PermitRootLogin"
    line: "PermitRootLogin no"
    state: present
  notify: Restart SSH

- name: Disable SSH password authentication
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: "^PasswordAuthentication"
    line: "PasswordAuthentication no"
    state: present
  notify: Restart SSH

- name: run all handlers now so it doesn't fail later in provisioning playbook
  meta: flush_handlers
```

The handler `Restart SSH` is as follows:

```
---

- name: Restart SSH
  service:
    name: sshd
    state: restarted
```

When I run this playbook, it runs all the tasks of the `ssh` role, but then fails at the last step of running the handler that restarts the `sshd` service, presumably because password login is now disabled?

```
PLAY [new_servers] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [cm002]

TASK [Run ssh role to enable login using SSH keys and disable password login] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ssh : Set SSH port] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [cm002] => changed=true
  backup: ''
  msg: line added

TASK [ssh : Disable root SSH login] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [mauocmacst002] => changed=true
  backup: ''
  msg: line added

TASK [ssh : Disable SSH password authentication] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************changed: [mauocmacst002] => changed=true
  backup: ''
  msg: line added

RUNNING HANDLER [ssh : Restart SSH] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************fatal: [cm002]: FAILED! =>
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: user@cm002: Permission denied (publickey).'

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
cm002              : ok=0   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

How do I restart the `sshd` service which is needed to be done for the changes to go into effect?

Comment: I believe you can use `set_fact:` and [`ansible_private_key_file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/connection/ssh.html#parameter-private_key_file) to change the ansible authentication mechanism after the ssh keypair is generated, thus switching ansible connectivity to use the new keypair -- have you tried that?

Comment: @mdaniel thanks, I haven't tried that but I realized the cause of the error is because I added the SSH argument `-o ServerAliveInterval=60` to my `ansible.cfg` file to keep the server from disconnecting from host during long task executions like `apt-get dist-upgrade`. With this argument, it seems Ansible tries to re-establish a SSH connection with the host and errors out as it cannot use a password anymore. You think using `set_fact` to use `ansible_private_key_file` is the way to get both desired effects, or is there another way?